# FileSystem vs FileSystemProvider

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am new to vscode extensions API development. I was going through the [API documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) when I found [FileSystem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem) and [FileSystemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider) in order to read a directory's and file's contents. I am finding it hard to understand the differences between the two.

Can someone help me out with when to use FileSystem and FileSystemProvider?

Comment: Did you read the respective descriptions? What's unclear about them and how would an answer be different?

Comment: Yeah, I did read the descriptions. I am not able to differentiate them. Or maybe I did not understand it correctly, I guess. Can you please explain the differences in simple words so that I can understand? Different scenarios to explain them would be appreciated. @MathieuGuindon

Comment: I was able to read the directory using fs . i.e. FileSystem then what's the use of FileSystemProvider?

Comment: Not familiar with the API, but the way I read it you would implement a `FileSystemProvider` if you wanted to extend VSCode with a custom file system. Providers usually _provide_ services; the documentation is indeed surprising, says `FileSystem` "exposes" the providers, but there's no `Providers` property there, so it's unclear how the providers are "exposed". But yeah I'd go with `fs`; a use-case for `FileSystemProvider` would likely be more involved than just reading files and folders.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for helping me out. @MathieuGuindon Yeah it seems like Provider is basically used for implementing or building custom FileSystem. Going through a repo code in samples code, where they are trying to rebuild a file structure but haven't mentioned exactly what they were doing. But now it makes sense.

Sample code link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/fsprovider-sample/